# On the formula, $\pi = \frac 5\varphi\cdot\frac 2{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}\cdot\frac 2{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}}\cdots$

Tags: pi, infinite-product, nested-radicals, golden-ratio

I found a formula on google images when I was looking at some formulas for $\pi$ just for the fun of it, and I came across one that really startled me, and was quite reminiscent of [Viète's product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula).

> Let $\varphi = \cfrac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ then $$\pi = \cfrac 5\varphi\cdot\cfrac 2{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}\cdot\cfrac 2{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}}\cdot\cfrac 2{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}}}\cdots$$

The [source](https://twitter.com/johncarlosbaez/status/848212575636512768) is from a Twitter post from someone who claimed that Ramanujan showed them this formula in a dream. Now, I don't quite know what to say to that, so I'll leave that to you.

What I'm looking for is a way to *prove* this. It is not often that I see a formula describing a relationship between $\pi$ and $\varphi$ but I am aware that the nested radicals seem to mimic ones like shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals) (which, as a matter of fact, shows that some radical formulae of my own have been rediscovered... but that's another story). Plugging several iterations in Wolfram Alpha, it does appear convincing.

Those nested radicals represent trigonometric functions, and $\pi$ is certainly involved there.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

Actually, according to the third link, I've made a conjecture which, if true, could surely help in proving this:

> $$2\cos \cfrac{\pi}{20}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}$$ $$2\cos \cfrac{\pi}{40}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}$$ $$2\cos \cfrac{\pi}{80}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}}$$ $$\vdots$$

If the conjectured pattern is true indefinitely, then the formula can be restated as $$\pi = \cfrac{5}{\varphi}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \cfrac{1}{\cos \frac{\pi}{20 \cdot 2^{n-1}}}$$

---

**Edit 2:**

This formula above involving $\pi$ and $\varphi$ actually contains a very hidden surprise! If you isolate $\pi\varphi\div 5$, this is equal to the square of a very elegant integral. Namely, $$\cfrac{\pi\varphi}{5} = \cfrac 2{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}\cdot\cfrac 2{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\varphi}}}}\cdots$$ $$=\Bigg\{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos\big(2x^2\big)\,\mathrm dx\Bigg\}^2$$ This, indubitably, is something which Ramanujan would highly commend :)

Comment: 2 minutes in and I already got an upvote and a star? Thank you, kind user! :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thanks for the edit!

Comment: Hint: $\varphi = 2\cos\frac{\pi}{5}$ and $\sqrt{2 + 2\cos\theta} = 2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Comment: The last restated formula was incorrect. I corrected it, sorry about that.

Comment: @peter.petrov don't be sorry, I was in a rush and was being sloppy. Thank you for the edit!

Comment: @MrPie This more general [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581518/is-this-general-nested-radical-for-pi-true) should be of interest. I'm sure you can see the connections, though I didn't realize particular cases of the general formula had been asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with Euler's identity

$$ \frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos \left(\frac{x}{2^k} \right) $$

which is readily derived from the sine angle duplication formula. Setting $ x = \pi/10 $ gives

$$ \frac{\varphi - 1}{\pi/5} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{20 \cdot 2^{k-1}} \right) $$

$$ \frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{1}{5(\varphi - 1)} \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{20 \cdot 2^{k-1}} \right) = \frac{\varphi}{5} \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{20 \cdot 2^{k-1}} \right) $$

after noting that $ \varphi (\varphi - 1) = 1 $, which finishes the proof given your observation. To prove that one, just remember the cosine angle duplication identity,

$$ 2 \cos(x/2) = \sqrt{2 \cos(x) + 2} $$

Comment: That is brilliant! Substituting $x=\cfrac{\pi}{6}$ gives: $$\cfrac{\pi}3 = \cfrac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}}\cdot \cfrac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}}}\cdot \cfrac{2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}}}}\cdots$$

Comment: The same result in your answer is also obtained by substituting $x=2\pi/5$, but that way uses more cancelling out since $\sin(2\pi/5)=\cos(\pi/10)$. Anyways, congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$